# Why C# keyword not recognized?

Tags: c#, .net

I try to use the `outint`  feature from c# 7.

Here the code:

```
 int.TryParse(part, outint number);
```

but under "outint number" I get a red line with an error:

```
outint does not exist in the current context
```

The target framework of the application is .NET 5.0.

Any idea why outint not recognized?

Comment: `out int` not `outint`

Comment: `outint` isn't a keyword. `out` is a keyword. `int` is a type.

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier)...

Comment: Normally I would agree that something like this is "just a typo", but this syntax occurs in [example code](https://github.com/CodeConversations/csharp7-features-with-mads-torgersen) so there is more to it than that.

Comment: Its not that way in the official docs. I wouldnt rely on such from channel9.msdn, Mads wouldn't make such mistake as that.

Comment: That page has a lot of typos. The person maintaining that repo should be ashamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is `out` rather than `outint`. You will need to pass an `int` variable in after the keyword `out`. The result will be in the variable after this line of code.

Answer (score 2):

its `out int` not `outint` give a space in middle and try

Answer (score 1):

There is space needed after out keyword

```
int.TryParse(part, out int number);
```

Answer (score -1):

`outint` occurs in [the code sample from our interview with Mads Torgersen on Code Conversations](https://github.com/CodeConversations/csharp7-features-with-mads-torgersen), but that's not how it works and it also is not what was shown in the accompanying video.

The [documentation of the feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier#calling-a-method-with-an-out-argument) is more trust-worthy than such samples.

> Starting with C# 7.0, you can declare the `out` variable in the argument list of the method call, rather than in a separate variable declaration. This produces more compact, readable code, and also prevents you from inadvertently assigning a value to the variable before the method call. The following example is like the previous example, except that it defines the number variable in the call to the Int32.TryParse method.
>
> ```
> string numberAsString = "1640";
>
> if (Int32.TryParse(numberAsString, out int number))
>     Console.WriteLine($"Converted '{numberAsString}' to {number}");
> else
>     Console.WriteLine($"Unable to convert '{numberAsString}'");
> // The example displays the following output:
> //       Converted '1640' to 1640
> ```

By the way if the syntax did work like `outint`, without the space, then that would be really strange: maybe the feature would be restricted to some primitive types and `var`? How else could it work? General identifiers cannot be keywords, the language has no idea what you might name your types. Given this weirdness, it would be reasonable to suspect, even without looking at the documentation, that `outint` is probably not how the feature works.